# What is the horse breed that is used in Ashvamedha yagna?

Tags: animals, yajna, vedic-rituals, ashwamedha

Is it Equus sivalensis?
I remember them being white for the ritual but do we know the breed?

Comment: I don't think HSE takes History into account?

Answer (score 1):

*E. sivalensis* is thought to have gone extinct 10k–75k years ago during the late Pleistocene megafaunal extinction as no evidence of them has been found more recently than 75k years ago.¹ *Aśvamedha* (horse sacrifice) has been performed many times since then. [Here is a list of known *aśvamedha* from the Vedic Period to the 18th Century.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashvamedha#List_of_performers) Domesticated horses (*E. ferus*) were brought to India sometime after 4,000 years ago.²

The most detail we have about *aśvamedha* is from *Ashvamedhika Parva*, the 14th book of Mahabharata. The concept of species taxonomy is much more recent, so I don't think you will find an exact reference to the species in any scriptures or *itihāsa*. The above evidence points to the species in question being *E. ferus*.

---

1: §"The Siwalik equid," "[Harappan horse myths and the sciences](https://web.archive.org/web/20090110183012/http://www.hinduonnet.com/thehindu/op/2002/03/05/stories/2002030500130100.htm)," *The Hindu*, 5 Mar 2002
2: "The origins and spread of domestic horses from the Western Eurasian steppes," *Nature*, Librado, et al., 20 Oct 2021, doi: [10.1038/s41586-021-04018-9](https://doi.org/10.1038%2Fs41586-021-04018-9)

Comment: I know there is no scripture reference to this, but I like how you used some science and logic to figure out the answer. +1